# Account Time Settings

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, time

I have set up the Marketing Cloud time zones to GMT. Issue is that every other time setting (automations, imports, etc) run on Central Time. Is this a default setting or is there a way to set everything to GMT?

Comment: This really bothers me in file imports and exports, because when running them on short morning in GMT e.g. 4o´clock on date: 21.03.2018  the day parameter is different on GMT (will be 21.03.2018) and CT(20.03.2018) or whatever timezone the servers running on. Is there a way to manipulate these values?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The servers run on cst. You can add an intermediate step that adjusts for time differences with an OFFSET sql function

Comment: But the offset would only be useful when i would extract the values which are stored in dataviews or where i salesforce itself writes the date-values, right? This wouldnt help on the import file or data extract activities with wildcard parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server time is in CST. Stack 4 is on Mountain Time. Daylight savings is not observed.

[What is the system timezone in Marketing Cloud and does it consider DST?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257649/what-is-the-system-timezone-in-marketing-cloud-and-does-it-consider-dst/257654#257654)

Comment: TO add clarity Server time is always CST and never CDT, so during DST server time would be MDT/CST and non daylight servertime would be CST/CST