# What is the system timezone in Marketing Cloud and does it consider DST?

Tags: marketing-cloud, timezone

My understanding is that the system timezone is CST. Is this correct? When Day Light Saving time occurs does this change to CDT?

Comment: They’re two different questions.

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions on the same topic/question - this can cause other valid questions to be 'lost in the shuffle' due to the influx of your identical questions and is not fair to those users.

Comment: How? The answer is a link to that question. How would they be different? Also, if you note, you have 4 questions within 3 hours all on the same issue with time zones.

Comment: Three completely different questions around the same topic. The first being quite generic so I broke them down into smaller specific questions. This one specifically asks about what timezone is used in MC and if it changes with DST, the one you marked it similar to asks about how times are stored between SC and MC.

Comment: It will be reviewed and I don't mean to come down hard, but this question also has been asked multiple times and is documented on the SFMC site. I do not see the value in separating it into 3 when it can easily (and was) answered in your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes system timezone is in CST and the server time does not change with standard versus daylight savings time.

[Why are Marketing Cloud timestamps not stored in the same timezone as Sales Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257650/why-are-marketing-cloud-timestamps-not-stored-in-the-same-timezone-as-sales-clou)