# Why are Marketing Cloud timestamps not stored in the same timezone as Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, timezone

I have both Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud connected and use data shared for a Journey when new records are created.

In my object that is triggered in the journey I have a Date/Time field which gets stored in SC in UTC, however in MC timezone settings are not stored in the field.

This means when using functions like `SystemDateToLocalDate(@recordTimestamp)` returns the wrong time as it thinks the original date is in CST (the system timezone instead of UTC).

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is expected. Server times for ExactTarget/Marketing Cloud is in CST: Central Standard Time (UTC minus six hours) and also the server time does not change with standard versus daylight savings time.

There are some weird behaviors with different stacks. Apparently Stack 4 is in US Mountain time (UTC minus 7 hours).

Comment: This is weird because their documentation says otherwise: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_integration_for_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5. In the documentation it gives an example where if the date was `09/29/2016 00:00 AM` in SC, it would be stored as `09/28/2016 07:00 PM` in MC, but from my testing its not its still `09/29/2016 00:00 AM`. In my test I simply queried out the data extension and stored to a text field which should bypass any UI time offsets.

Comment: That's interesting. So what timezone are you seeing in MC?

Comment: The account is set to GMT * (The * indicates its observing DST so its really BST). So for example a date I stored was `2019/04/14 8:15:00 AM`, this is stored as `2019/04/14 7:15:00 AM` in SC as they store all timestamps in UTC. In my data extension inside MC this is stored as `Apr 14 2019  7:15AM`, this is also the value queried out as a string.

Comment: See this quote in the same link you provided "Ensure that you use the proper offset when manipulating date and time information synchronized from the Sales Cloud to the Marketing Cloud." My interpretation is that they are telling us the date is stored in CST in MC in the event you are manipulating the data after it gets to MC. It's telling you that it is NOT stored in GMT as it is on SFDC. In other words, while the numbers are different, those both represent the exact same time.

Comment: How I've interpreted that last line is that we must use offsets get back to the original timezone and this would be totally fine if the times stored between SC and MC were different. But they're not, they are the same values, just in MC its assumed that timezone is CST. The documentation states it will actually store whatever the *converted* CST time is. In my example above it should have stored `2:15AM` instead of `7:15AM`.

Comment: So are we saying the statement in the document about what time would be stored is incorrect? and that we should use offsets to display/output the correct time?